# Materialized View has stop refreshing after index creation in oracle. Is recompile required post index creation?

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW "FCSMARC"."CS_LOAN_RECEIPT_DTL" ("ACCOUNTNO", "AGREEMENTID", "CUSTOMERNAME", "RECEIPTNO", "CHEQUENUM", "RECEIPT_AMOUNT", "PAYMENT_TYPE", "INSTRUMENT_TYPE", "DRAWNON", "CITY", "CHEQUEDATE")
ORGANIZATION HEAP 
PCTFREE 10 
PCTUSED 40 
INITRANS 1 
MAXTRANS 255 
NOCOMPRESS 
LOGGING 
STORAGE(
        INITIAL 1048576 
        NEXT 1048576 
        MINEXTENTS 1 
        MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 
        PCTINCREASE 0 
        FREELISTS 1 
        FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
       ) 
TABLESPACE "MAIN_TBL" BUILD IMMEDIATE USING INDEX REFRESH START WITH SYSDATE NEXT SYSDATE + 2/24 
USING DEFAULT LOCAL ROLLBACK SEGMENT USING ENFORCED CONSTRAINTS DISABLE QUERY REWRITE
AS 
SELECT accountno,agreementid,customername,receiptno,chequenum,receipt_amount,payment_type, instrument_type,drawnon,city,chequedate FROM cs_loan_receipt_dtl_rl@fcsmarc_to_collstage UNION ALL
SELECT accountno,agreementid,customername,receiptno,chequenum,receipt_amount,payment_type, instrument_type,drawnon,city,chequedate
```

Comment: the tail `FROM ....` is missing ...

Comment: Please include the DDL for the index or anything else that changed, too.

Comment: I have created normal index. create index idx_CS_LOAN_RECEIPT_001 on CS_LOAN_RECEIPT_DTL(unit_code,status,TRUNC(FINN_TRAN_DATE),accountno) online;